# Fitnesse problems loading dll

Tags: .net, fitnesse

I am having trouble loading the that.dll contains my test classes that call into my work.dll.

I can do it nicely with a helloworld.dll but when I put the helloworld test in my test.dll, It cannot load, even after I remove my work.dll references from the test.dll

I think the problem her is that the path to the work.dll is not known by Fitness, how do I specify it? ( preferebly in the root page)

the error messages I get are:

```
System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Projects\..\test.dll' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
File name: 'file:///C:\Projects\..\test.dll'
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadFrom(String assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue, AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile)
   at fitSharp.Machine.Engine.CurrentDomain.LoadAssembly(String assemblyPath)
   at fitSharp.Machine.Engine.ApplicationUnderTest.Assemblies.AddAssembly(String assemblyName)
   at fitSharp.Machine.Engine.ApplicationUnderTest.AddAssemblies(IEnumerable`1 assemblyNames)
   at fitnesse.fitserver.FitServer.ParseCommandLineArguments(IEnumerable`1 args)
   at fitnesse.fitserver.FitServer.Run(IList`1 CommandLineArguments)
   at fitnesse.fitserver.FitServer.Run(IList`1 commandLineArguments, Memory memory, ProgressReporter reporter)
   at fitSharp.Machine.Application.Shell.Run()
   at fitSharp.Machine.Application.Shell.Execute()
   at fitSharp.Machine.Application.Shell.Run(IList`1 commandLineArguments)

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = kenneth
LOG: Where-ref bind. Location = C:\Projects\..\test.dll
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Projects/fitnesse/dotnet2/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Projects\fitnesse\dotnet2\Runner.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Projects/../test.dll.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing terminated.
```

Does anyone have any clues/tips.

thanks
kenneth

Comment: I've investigate further, and the problem appears to be dependend on what type of target platform I am compiling to. When I make a dummy test and compile to AnyCPU it appears to work nicely. But when I link to the work.dll - that is compiled to x86, it no longer loads. ( I get a MSIL warning, due to the 86/64 issue) Any ideas on how to workaround this (except compile the referenced projects to 64 bit - I am running on 64 bit win 7)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was running a 64 bit testrunner, and testing / loading 32 bit dlls.
To solve this I ran CorFlags.exe on TestRunner.exe with the /32BIT+ flag set.
you can get Corflags from the SDK.

Answer (score 3):

You can only load DLLs that match the bitness of your application's process. That's what the `BadImageFormatException` is trying to tell you, that you've attempted to load an incompatible DLL.

So if you have a 32-bit (x86) process, you can only load 32-bit (x86) DLLs.
And if you have a 64-bit (x64) process, you can only load 64-bit (x64) DLLs.

The "Any CPU" compiler setting just means that the bitness of the process will match the native bitness of your machine: 64-bit on a 64-bit OS, 32-bit otherwise.

You will need to either obtain a version of the DLL that matches the bitness of your application, or re-compile your application to target a different bitness.

Comment: yes it looks like youre rigth. the problem is that i am running on a 64 bit mashine, where i am developing 32 bit dll's. appearently fitnesse testrunner will expect 64 bit, and not 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the FitSharp instructions for adding your code to the classpath:

- http://www.syterra.com/Slim/GettingStarted.html
- http://www.syterra.com/Fit/UsingFitnesse.html

Answer (score 0):

Based on the BadImageFormatException, you appear to have a mismatch between your DLL's .net version and the test runner's .net version.